# Hidden remote function call of a local binding in ocaml

Tags: functional-programming, ocaml

Given the following example for generating a lazy list number sequence:

```
type 'a lazy_list = Node of 'a * (unit -> 'a lazy_list);;

let make = 
    let rec gen i = 
        Node(i, fun() -> gen (i + 1))
    in gen 0
;;
```

I asked myself the following questions when trying to understand **how** the example works (obviously I could not answer myself and therefore I am asking here)

- When calling `let Node(_, f) = make` and then `f()`, why does the call of `gen 1` inside `f()` succeed although `gen` is a local binding only existing in `make`?
- Shouldn't the created `Node` be completely  unaware of the existence of `gen`? (Obviously not since it works.)
- How is a construction like this being handled by the compiler?

Comment: All of these questions are answered by the concept of a [closure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_programming)).

Comment: Thank you, the picture is now more than clear! I knew I was missing something very basic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, the questions that are asking have nothing to do with the concepts of lazy, so we can disregard this particular issue, to simplify the discussion.

As Jeffrey noted in the comment to your question, the answer is simple - it is a closure.

But let me extend it a little bit. Functional programming languages, as well as many other modern languages, including Python and C++, allows to define functions in a scope of another function and to refer to the variables available in the scope of the enclosing function. These variables are called captured variables, and the created functional object along with the captured values is called the closure.

From the compiler perspective, the implementation is rather simple (to understand). The closure is a normal value, that contains a code to be executed, as well as pointers to the extra values, that were captured from the outer scope. Since OCaml is a garbage collected language, the values are preserved, as they are referenced from a live object. In C++ the story is much more complicated, as C++ doesn't have the GC, but this is a completely different story.

> Shouldn't the created Node be completely unaware of the existence of gen? (Obviously not since it works.)

The create `Node` is an object that has two pointers, a pointer to the initial object `i`, and a pointer to the anonymous function `fun() -> gen (i + 1)`. The anonymous function has a pointer to the same initial object `i`. In our particular case, the `i` is an integer, so instead of being a pointer the `i` value is represented inline, but these are details that are irrelevant to the question.

Comment: Thank you for your time and the descriptive answer! 
And indeed, my question has nothing to do with the concepts of lazy. It's just for the sake of the example.